# Linear Transformation. How to prove that T(x) = S(x) for all x $\epsilon\ R^2$

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

let $v_1 = \begin{bmatrix}1 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix}$ and $v_2 = \begin{bmatrix}1 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix}$. Assume that the linear transformations T(x) and S(x) satisfy T($v_1$) = S($v_1$) and T($v_2$) = S($v_2$). Prove that T(x) = S(x) for all x $\epsilon\ R^2$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $v_1,v_2$ are linearly independent,

> given an $\textbf{x} \in \mathbb{R}^2$, you can write it uniquely as: $$\textbf{x} = a^1v_1+a^2v_2$$

Since $T$ is linear:

> $T(\textbf{x}) = a^1T(v_1)+a^2T(v_2)$....(take it from here).

Comment: Try to work through without scrolling over the yellow boxes.